# textplot::plot.BTM(): Avoid thick edges and weird colors in cluster visualization

Tags: r, plot, cluster-computing, visualization, topic-modeling

#### Goal and Tools

I currently try to familiarize with the *R* packages [`BTM`](https://github.com/bnosac/BTM) and [`textplot`](https://github.com/bnosac/textplot), that is how to create readable and meaningful visualizations of biterm topic models (BTM models) created with `BTM` via `textplot`. `textplot::plot.BTM()` is a method that creates a cluster visualization of models created with `BTM::BTM()`. Both the documentation of `BTM::BTM()` and the documentation of `textplot::plot.BTM()` contain code examples dedicated to plotting. According to the documentation, `textplot::plot.BTM()` returns an object of class `ggplot`.

#### Previous Attempts and Observations

After installing the packages mentioned in these examples, namely `concaveman`, `ggraph` and `igraph`, I could successfully replicate these example plots. Also, my own plots looked like the examples.

Though, when I start with a fresh R session and run my script (*see minimal code below*), my plots suddenly look different. The colors of the cluster shapes and especially the edges are no longer light pastel shades like in the [demo plots](https://github.com/bnosac/textplot/blob/master/vignettes/textplot-examples.gif), but rather dark and bright shades, e.g. a dark brown that yields a low contrast regarding the black tokens (*[see this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYcvX.png)*). Besides that, the edges have become extremely thick, so they cover and exceed the cluster shapes underneath. That way, the plot is unreadable and definitely looks broken. Very weird.

I have noticed that *R* outputs something like*

```r
Load required namespace: ggraph
Load required namespace: concaveman
```

when I run `textplot::plot.BTM()`, although sometimes only `concaveman` is mentioned for an unknown reason. Calling `class()` indicates the return value is of class `ggraph` which inherits from `ggplot`. It seems to me that these packages are properly installed and used by the function if needed. All involved packages are updated, that is `BTM` 0.3.1 and `textplot` 0.1.2 are installed to explicitly mention the core package versions.

**I get these in German and translated literally.*

#### My Questions

1. How can I ensure that my plots always look as intended, that is have light pastel shades and adequately sized edges?
2. Why do my plots look differently, that is have bright dark shades and extremly thick edges?
3. *Bonus question in terms of readability ;)* : How can I ensure that *all* tokens have a readable font size? I noticed in both my and the example plots, that tokens with a low frequency are very tiny and, thus, hard to read.

Many thanks for your help!

This is my first post on *stackoverflow* ever, so please let me know if I missed best practices of asking questions.

#### Minimal Code

```r
library(BTM)
library(textplot)
library(udpipe)
    
data("brussels_reviews_anno", package = "udpipe")
brussel_reviews <- subset(brussels_reviews_anno, language == "nl")
brussel_reviews <- subset(brussel_reviews, xpos %in% c("NN", "NNP", "NNS"))
brussel_reviews <- brussel_reviews[, c("doc_id", "lemma")]
    
btm_model <- BTM(brussel_reviews, k = 5)
    
plot(btm_model, top_n = 15,
     title = "Topic Clusters of Top 15 Biterms",
     labels = c("1 - Too dark color masking terms",
                "2 - Looks okish",
                "3 - Too thick edges",
                "4 - Too thick edges",
                "5 - Too thick edges"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have actually found the answer to question 2 shortly after posting my question, but also got in touch with the developer of the `BTM` package to clarify question 1 and would like to share with you in my own words. Though, I might not explain every detail completely accurately, so corrections are welcome.

#### Summary

1. **How correct?** Attach the `ggraph` package in *every* session (*see corrected minimal code below*).
2. **Why wrong?** With `ggraph` attached, the plot is drawn with another method added by `ggraph`.
3. **How ensure readable tokens?** I see no option, because we cannot change that some tokens very rarely cooccur with their neighbor terms. Still, a readable minimal display size could be introduced. I will consider a smaller sliding window to avoid rare biterms with e.g. `BTM::BTM(window = 5)`.

#### Corrected Minimal Code

```r
library(BTM)
library(ggraph)
library(textplot)
library(udpipe)

[...]
```

#### Details

1. **How?** For `BTM` plots to look as expected, you not only have to install the packages
   `concaveman`, `ggraph` and `igraph`, but **to attach the `ggraph` package in *every* session**. (Of course, also `BTM` is needed to produce BTM models to visualize.)
   Looking at the documentation of `BTM`and `textplot`, it is striking that `ggraph` is *always* attached in any example code. At first, though, I understood the lists as which packages need to be installed, not necessarily to be attached, especially after seeing the package lists vary from example to example:
   `BTM::BTM()` mentions:

```r
library(igraph)
library(BTM)
library(ggraph)
```

`textplot::plot.BTM()` mentions:

```r
library(textplot)
library(ggraph)
library(concaveman)
```

`textplot::textplot_bitermclusters()`, the underlying function, mentions:

```r
library(igraph)
library(ggraph)
library(concaveman)
library(BTM)
```

2. **Why?** Plots look differently with my minimal code, because **the package `ggraph` is not attached**. Attaching `ggraph` is not necessary for plot objects to be *produced* properly by `plot.BTM()`, but for the plot objects to be *printed* correctly. More precisely, `ggraph` plots via ggplot2::print.ggplot(), but extends the internal generic function `ggplot2::ggplot_build()` by a method for `ggraph` objects, namely `ggplot_build.ggraph()`. There, the algorithm of how to plot is temporarily changed before calling `ggplot_build.ggplot()`, yielding the different, more pleasant look.
3. **Ensure readable tokens?** In `textplot::plot.BTM()`, it seems that the token size depends on how often the token cooccurs with its neighbor tokens within a topic cluster. I would like the option to set a meaningful minimal display size, because I see no point in including tokens I cannot read, especially given that I cannot infer the frequency from the token size that precisely anyway. One thing to try is to narrow the sliding window which biterms are build in via e.g. `BTM::BTM(window = 5)`. That way, I might avoid too many rare combinations of tokens and, thus, tiny tokens in the plot. I am not sure, though.